# Rails 5.2 ActionController::UnknownFormat in PatientsController#index error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  #require 'pry';  binding.pry
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: Patient.all
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I thought `respond_to` is included in rails? If I put a pry I can see `request.format == :html` is `true` Thanks for any help!

UDPATE:
after changing to

```
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: Patient.all
      end
      format.html do
        render :index
      end
    end
end
```

It works!

Comment: You have not specified a response for an "html" request so making one results in your error. If you were to visit "/patients.json" you should receive a response. If this should default to a json request then specify the format in your routes [Rails routing 3.5 Defining Defaults](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks that was the problem! IT is working now

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the error message `ActionController::UnknownFormat` is telling you what is wrong.

As you mentioned, `request.format` returns `:html` but you only have `format.json` defined.

It looks like you don't format your JSON request properly. In order to do that you either should define headers for a JSON request or make request to the url that ends with `.json` (a feature from rails).

JSON request headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```